# User profile pictures not showing up in one site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have 3 site collections and we think we have an issue with one regarding the user profile pictures. In that site collection, the user profile pictures do not show up in the lists. We do the same to the two other site collections and the pictures immediately show up.

We already reached out to Microsoft but so far, we have only done some incremental synchronization, code running, log looking, etc. Has anyone encountered the issue before? As it is only happening to one of the site collections, it is hard to figure out what is causing it.

Any ideas will be much appreciated. Also, we have deleted the user profiles and waited for them to synch but it is still the same.

Thanks,

Karen